# Apache Beam TextIO.Read with line number

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Is it possible to get access to line numbers with the lines read into the PCollection from TextIO.Read? For context here, I'm processing a CSV file and need access to the line number for a given line.

If not possible through TextIO.Read it seems like it should be possible using some kind of custom Read or transform, but I'm having trouble figuring out where to begin.

Comment: You might need to inherit from the textIO and add your custom logic to output a tuple <line, line_number>. Or as an alternative, add this LINE_NUMBER to each line of your CSV FILE as an extra column (I mean to modify your input file content); then you can use the original textIO and a followup DoFn to extract the linenumber.

Comment: Any pointers on how to inherit from textIO? Not really seeing in there where I'd have access to grab the line number.

Comment: So I guess you cannot modify your input data by adding one extra column?  then, I guess you have to start from filebasedsource.FileBasedSource probably (python:https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/filebasedsource.py#L201). Implement your own read_records() method which returns an iterator that gives the 2-tuple (line, line number). You can make `splittable` = False for the new `source` class you introduced so the logic would be much easier (at least to start with).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`FileIO`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.html) to read the file manually, where you can determine the line number when you read from the [`ReadableFile`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.ReadableFile.html).

A simple solution can look as follows:

```java
p
    .apply(FileIO.match().filepattern("/file.csv"))
    .apply(FileIO.readMatches())
    .apply(FlatMapElements
            .into(strings())
            .via((FileIO.ReadableFile f) -> {
                List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
                try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(Channels.newReader(f.open(), "UTF-8"))) {
                    int lineNr = 1;
                    String line = br.readLine();
                    while (line != null) {
                        result.add(lineNr + "," + line);
                        line = br.readLine();
                        lineNr++;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Error while reading", e);
                }
                return result;
            }));
```

The solution above just prepends the line number to each input line.